# Applescript to attach file to Mail Message. Worked in OSX 10.4 to 10.6 will not work in 10.8

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion, email-attachments

With 10.8, My Applescript (developed when I was running 10.4 thru 10.6) that reads a comma separate text file, uses the values to create a new mail message, then attachs a xx.pdf file using a NSstring path name to the file, still sends out the email, but does not include the attachment. I understand from researching the problem, that 10.8 security enhancements have "SANDBOXed" the Mail app and applescript apps so that the path name no longer works as a valid, passible link to the file. I have found several examples that claim to fix the problem, Claiming that the NSstring "file name:" must be replaced with file name in NSURL format, but the code does not look like applescript, and will not compile in the applescript editor. Do you have an example of applescript that will attach the file to a new, applescript generated email message? I have been trying for days to solve this problem without success. I even called the Apple Support line, but they said the do not support Applescript related problems any more.

The variable that I pass in from the text file is named "theAttachment1". The line I am trying to get working is:

"make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment1} at after the last paragraph

Again, it works fine in 10.4 thru 10.6, but will not work in 10.8.

Comment: Can you post your full script and an an example of the text file with the file paths. I Assume you are also talking about string and file url rather the NSString ...

Comment: How was this Solved ??. If it was my answer you should accept it. If another way then please explain it so others get the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on 10.8

```
   set theAttachment1 to POSIX file "/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Desktop--IMAGE/scooter-6.jpg"

tell application "Mail"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"subject", content:"the_content" & return & return}
    tell newMessage

        set visible to false
        set sender to "myaddress@btinternet.com"
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"someAddress@btinternet.com"}
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment1} at after the last paragraph

        (* change save to send to send*)
        save --<<<<---------------- change save to send to send
        (* change save to send to send*)
    end tell
end tell
```

The path can be either a Unix path :**"/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Desktop--IMAGE/scooter-6.jpg"**
or a Posix file path : **"Macintosh HD:Users:USERNAME:Desktop:Desktop--IMAGE:scooter-6.jpg"**

In this script I converted the path from a Unix path to a Posix file path